# What methods are needed to create a custom Python Enum subclass?

Tags: python, enums

My goal is to create a custom Enum subclass, similar to IntEnum or StrEnum, to contain tuples as values.
However, I'm not sure which are the magic methods I should consider. So far, this is my current state:

```
class TupleEnum(enum.Enum):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, enum.Enum):
            return self.value == other.value
        else:
            return self.value == other
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
```

That allows me to compare the class with tuples and to access mapping values. However, I do not know which one I should code to also compute its value into a function.
For example, comparing an IntEnum I get the following:

```
class Numbers(enum.IntEnum):
    A = 1
    B = 2

class Tuples(TupleEnum):
    A = (0, 0, 0)
    b = (1, 1, 1)

np.array([Numbers.A, Numbers.B])
>>> array([1, 2])

np.array([Tuples.A, Tuples.B])
>>> array([<Tuples.A: (0, 0, 0)>, <Tuples.B: (1, 1, 1)>])
```

Which method am I missing to obtain an array similar to the one with the IntEnum?
Also, would you recommend any other method? (Of course, `__str__` will be included later)

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to my own question.
By running `help(enum.IntEnum)` I could see its constructor as `class IntEnum(builtins.int, ReprEnum)`

So, for the purpose I am aiming for, the following snippet is all I need:

```
class TupleEnum(builtins.tuple, enum.ReprEnum):
    """Enumeration where members are tuples"""

class Tuples(TupleEnum):
    A = (0, 0, 0)
    B = (1, 1, 1)
```

Also JFI, ReprEnum only changes `__repr__`